# Python3: What is the most efficient way to handle bar delimited files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to write something that can parse a `txt` file looks something like this:

```
TOP1|TOP2|TOP3
Group1|Value2|Value3
Group2|Value2|Value3
TAIL1|TAIL2|TAIL3
```

- `TOP` and `TAIL` will always be the same structure, however, the structure of `Group` will change. I.E: each file has its own groups, which have their own values.
- These files are only a few KB each and I need a way to scale this to 100k+/day file parses.
- I have had a look at Hadoop, but not sure if its overkill for my use case.

For some reason, I feel using a simple: `with open()` isn't the most efficient - In addition, I am trying to avoid using integer indexing to get the files attributes.

Ideally I want to map the file to a Python Dict and then to a customer `Top`, `Tail` class. I also have a `Groups` class which will be a list of all the rows in the file under `Group`.

The structure is loosely described by this:  `FILE --> [Top, [Group1, Group2], Tail]`.

So far I have this, but its not suitable:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file:
    items = []
    for line in file:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        d = {}
        data = line.split('|')
        print(data)
        for val in data:
            key, sep, value = val.partition(',')
            d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        items.append(d)
```

Comment: Is this just a csv file with bars rather than commas? csv readers are flexible in which delimiter they use. In any event, maybe try pandas.

Comment: What do you mean by "not suitable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in order to read a file using the delimiter of your choice (in this case `|`).

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt, sep="|", engine='python')
```

Comment: Maybe this is all they need and it is certainly a reasonable approach, but when they write "TOP and TAIL will always be the same structure, however, the structure of Group will change" suggests that it might be more complicated than that. Hard to know unless they clarify.

Comment: Will `read_csv()` work if the file isnt a CSV. Also how will I keep the hierarchy of the groups

Comment: @Bob yes it will work. Even though the file extension is `.csv`, the content is actually delimiter-separated

Comment: Ahh great, I will give pandas a go